# pip3 support in Heroku Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, heroku, rasa

I am trying to deploy a Python app based on Rasa on Heroku and am trying to obtain dependencies which can be obtained from pip3 or the latest versions of pip (eg tensorflow 1.15 needed by rasa, hwere my build fails).

Does Heroku support pip3 yet ?

If yes, how can I set Heroku to use it during build ?

I get that lowering rhe Rasa version in requirements.txt works fine and picks up the available lower version of tensorflow (1.14 or lower), though I am curious to know if we can use pip3 and why isn't pip being able to fetch tensorflow 1.15

Comment: which errors exactly are you seeing when installing `tensorflow`? 

Heroku's default python runtime is a python3 one, so `pip3` and `pip` is actually the same command with a different name.

Comment: the error is that the dependency `tensorflow=1.15` is not found while installing rasa

Answer (score 0):

As of now they have supported

```
python-3.8.0 on all supported runtime stacks
python-3.7.5 on all supported runtime stacks
python-3.6.9 on all supported runtime stacks
python-2.7.17 on all supported runtime stacks
```

Also, it is relying on the virtual environment you are stacking under your project.
More documentation from heroku (They have updated yesterday) - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes

Comment: Hi Sahil,
I am trying to deploy the app directly from my github branch.
The deploy build there is causing the issue, and not my local environment.
Any idea on how I could switch to pip3 instead of pip (and not the python version) in that deploy build ?

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of the error and as per my knowledge Heroku builds the app on the basis of the version you have mentioned in your build spec file.

Comment: Yes, true it builds the app on thr basis of the version mentioned in requirements.txt.

Comment: Though i can solve the issue by using an older version of rasa whcih uses tensorflow, i am concerned why Heroku cannot find the latest version of tensorflow for the latest version of rasa specified.